# How do you make a value inside a for loop that isn't the i value incrementally decrease?

Tags: java, arrays, intersection, rectangles

I am writing a program to identify which rectangles intersect eachother based on the rectangles and the corner coordinates that a user inputs. I am trying to create a for loop that checks for each rectangle, which rectangles (input by user) intersect it. In the for loop, I am trying to make the program check one rectangle against every other rectangle to see if they intersect and attempting to do this as follows:

```
package a1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A1Jedi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

           process(s);
    }

    public static void process(Scanner s) {
        String[] rectnames;
        int[] xcoordinate1;
        int[]ycoordinate1;
        int[]xcoordinate2;
        int[]ycoordinate2;
        int[]xcoordinate3;
        int[]ycoordinate3;
        int[]xcoordinate4;
        int[]ycoordinate4;
        String[] intersectrectnames;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rectangles as an integer");


      int rectnum;
      rectnum = s.nextInt();

      rectnames = new String[rectnum];
    xcoordinate1 = new int[rectnum];
    ycoordinate1 = new int[rectnum];
    xcoordinate2 = new int[rectnum];
    ycoordinate2 = new int[rectnum];
    xcoordinate3 = new int[rectnum];
    ycoordinate3 = new int[rectnum];
    xcoordinate4 = new int[rectnum];
    ycoordinate4 = new int[rectnum];
    intersectrectnames = new String[rectnum-1];

       for(int i = 0; i<rectnum; i++){
           System.out.println("PLease enter the rectangle's name as a single letter");

           String rectname;
           rectname = s.next();
           rectnames[i] = rectname;

           System.out.println("Please enter the x value of one coordinate of the rectangle" );
           int xcoor1;
           xcoor1 = s.nextInt();
           xcoordinate1[i]= xcoor1;

           System.out.println("Please enter the y value of the same coordinate of the rectangle");
           int ycoor1;
           ycoor1 = s.nextInt();
           ycoordinate1[i]= ycoor1;

           System.out.println("Please enter the x value of annother coordinate of the rectangle");

           int xcoor2;
           xcoor2 = s.nextInt();
           xcoordinate2[i]= xcoor2;

           System.out.println("Please enter the y value of the same coordinate of the rectangle");
           int ycoor2;
           ycoor2 = s.nextInt();
           ycoordinate2[i]= ycoor2;
       }


           for(int a=0; a < rectnum; a++) {
             for(int b=a+1; b < rectnum; b++) {

       if ((xcoordinate1[a]< xcoordinate2[b]) && (xcoordinate2[a] > xcoordinate1[b])
        && (ycoordinate1[a] < ycoordinate2[b]) && (ycoordinate2[a] > ycoordinate1[b])){

           intersectrectnames[a] = rectnames[b];  


       System.out.println(intersectrectnames[a]);
       }  
       }
       }}}
```

Comment: what is the error it's giving you?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at a1.A1Jedi.process(A1Jedi.java:71)
 at a1.A1Jedi.main(A1Jedi.java:7)

Comment: Do you really intend to decrement `rectnum` five times per loop? Because that's what your code is currently attempting to do.

Comment: Why do you keep subtracting 1 from `rectnum`?

Comment: how do i make it so rectnum is subtracted only once per loop, because that is what I want

Comment: Stop using `rectnum--` everywhere.

Comment: @user3440080 You may need to post more code if you can't figure it out from my solution. Keep us posted.

Comment: @user3440080 This may help (though it's complex). It computes what I think you're trying to do. It's more complex than I thought. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243734/intersecting-rectangles?rq=1

Comment: BTW: if you use rectangle objects instead of arrays with coordinates, you can actually [ask the rectangles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) if they intersect.

Comment: ok, i will. and i am trying out eckes solution.

Comment: just edited what i have now

Comment: The loop looks now OK, in your if you do not check all overlap combinations. You need to first check which one starts more left and more up, and then compare all 4 points for both of those cases. It helps a bit of you always are sure you have the upper left corner and the lower right, then you just need to check who is more left and who is more down.

Comment: BTW: if you dont upvote or accept answers its unlikely you get any more help from the people who took the time to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is decrementing `rectnum` five times per loop. It already happens at the top of the loop for each iteration. The operation `--rectnum` *changes* the value of `rectnum`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < --rectnum; i++) { // pre-decrement here

   if ((xcoordinate1[i] < xcoordinate2[rectnum]) && 
       (xcoordinate2[i] > xcoordinate1[rectnum]) && 
       (ycoordinate1[i] < ycoordinate2[rectnum]) && 
       (ycoordinate2[i] > ycoordinate1[rectnum])) {

       intersectrectnames[i] = rectnames[rectnum];  

    }
}
```

To have it five times like you did, without changing it, the code would be like this (possibly, I don't know what the full code does.):

```
for(int i = 0; i < rectnum; i++) {

   if ((xcoordinate1[i] < xcoordinate2[rectnum-1]) && 
       (xcoordinate2[i] > xcoordinate1[rectnum-1]) && 
       (ycoordinate1[i] < ycoordinate2[rectnum-1]) && 
       (ycoordinate2[i] > ycoordinate1[rectnum-1])) {

       intersectrectnames[i] = rectnames[rectnum-1];  

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok yeah, I think i see where i messed up now. think that for(int i =0; i< --rectnum; i++, rectnum--){ will work

Comment: So you still want it decremented twice in the loop declaration? Both `--rectnum` and `rectnum--` decrement it.

Comment: @user3440080 No, that would decrement it twice per loop.  You probably want `for(int i =0; i< rectnum; i++, rectnum--)`.

Comment: @Hosch250 And that is the same as `for(int i =0; i<rectnum--; i++)`

Comment: @mbomb007 I know, either way is fine.

Comment: ok, thanks. also, how could I get it to do this for every rectangle that the user inputs? would I need like a nested "for" loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops, as you want to step through pairs of rectangles. In this case the inner loop starts at the one which was compared already to avoid to compare them two times:

```
int recnum = xcoordinate1.length; // or any other way
for(int a=0; a < recnum; a++) {
  for(int b=a+1; b < recnum; b++) {
    if ((xcoordinate1[a] < xcoordinate2[b] ...)
    {
       System.out.println("rectangle " + a + " and " + b + " intersect");
    }
  }
}
```

this compares (if you have 4 rectangles)

```
a=0 with b=1, b=2, b=3
a=1 with b=2, b=3
a=2 with b=3
```

The outer loop will then also try to compare a=3, but the inner loop starts then with `b=3+1` which is not less than 4, so it is not executed anymore.

Your initial question was about the loop variables, so I skip the if logic. However you need to improve your if code as well, it must check all the different cases how retangles can be placed relative to each other (and on both dimensions). Hint: the if has at least 2 && combined expressions which contain multiple ors. You can either do it in a larger statement which takes into account all different combinations (who is more left and more down) or you first assign the one which is most left and most down and do the comparision with that fact in mind.

Comment: Add a description to your answer.

Comment: @mbomb007 sure, enter key sent too quick :) (and you guys do not give anybody a second to correct)

Comment: should the following code be a nested for loops that would work?  }
       for (int i = 0; i<rectnum; i++){
       for(i =0; i< rectnum; rectnum--){
       
       if ((xcoordinate1[i]< xcoordinate2[rectnum]) && (xcoordinate2[i] > xcoordinate1[rectnum])
     && (ycoordinate1[i] < ycoordinate2[rectnum]) && (ycoordinate2[i] > ycoordinate1[rectnum])){
        
        intersectrectnames[i] = rectnames[rectnum];  
        
 }
       }  
       }
       }}

Comment: @user3440080 no. but maybe you should tell us what `recnum` is. Is it maybe the number of rectangles? (I modify my code to use `recnum`  instead of `len`).

Comment: Wow. Please escape code with backticks (left of the `1` key). Add it to your question.

Comment: yeah its the number of rectangles that the user inputs